# Elasticsearch v5 analyzer demo example not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

When I try to do a demo with the ES website:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html 
- the latest example of a custom analyzer. This example does not work. I did not change anything, even in the example. I think it Elasticsearch error. Can anybody help me? Below I show the command and error that shows me Elastichsearch in the ubuntu terminal.
The same error occurs when i try to make this example in the elasticsearch-php.

First, i create analyzer, as his shown in example:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -d'
> {
>   "settings": {
>     "analysis": {
>       "analyzer": {
>         "std_folded": { 
>           "type": "custom",
>           "tokenizer": "standard",
>           "filter": [
>             "lowercase",
>             "asciifolding"
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "mappings": {
>     "my_type": {
>       "properties": {
>         "my_text": {
>           "type": "text",
>           "analyzer": "std_folded" 
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }'
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true
}
```

Good, analyzer created. But testing example not works:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze ?pretty' -d'
> {
>   "analyzer": "std_folded", 
>   "text":     "Is this déjà vu?"
> }'
```

And ES answer me:

```
{
"error":
    {"root_cause":
    [{
        "type":"index_not_found_exception",
        "reason":"no such index",
        "resource.type":"index_or_alias",
        "resource.id":"bad-request",
        "index_uuid":"_na_",
        "index":"bad-request"
    }],
    "type":"index_not_found_exception",
    "reason":"no such index",
    "resource.type":"index_or_alias",
    "resource.id":"bad-request",
    "index_uuid":"_na_",
    "index":"bad-request"},
"status":404
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I deleted all the indexes and create again, I tried to restart elasticsearch - but to no avail.
P.S. Excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GET request is incorrect. There shouldn't be a space between '_analyze' and '?pretty', so your curl should be

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty' -d'
```

followed by the query.

Comment: Thanks @ravi-naik! Its working! This means that the demo has a syntax error, because when I copy via the "COPY AS CURL", everything is copied with the wrong space.

Comment: Correct, I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/elastic/docs/issues/139), let's see if that gets resolved.